# setClickable() work backwards - Android Adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter, clickable

I'm doing my own Adapter to use in a GridView and represent a calendar. My problem is when I use setClickable() and setFocusable() set to false I can click on the layout... but if I set it to true I can´t... Thanks for the attention. I pasted my code.

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

            String item = items[position];

             vi=convertView;
             final TextView tv;

            if(convertView==null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dato, null);}

           tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textViewDia);

            if(item.equals("")){

                tv.setText(""+item);
                tv.setClickable(false);
                tv.setFocusable(false);
                tv.setEnabled(false);

            }
            else{
                 tv.setText(""+item);
            }



            return vi;  
        }
```

EDIT: I add this to my code like says in first answer but still working wrong:

```
 @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position){

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled(){

            return false;
        }
```

SOLUTION: I found the solution, is like says @FunkTheMonk but I understood wrong my bad english sorry =)

```
 @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position){
            if(items[position].equals(""))
            return false;

            else
                return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled(){

            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By making the layout clickable, it is consuming the click event.
When the layout isn't clickable, the click event is instead consumed by the `GridView`, and will be processed by any `OnItemClickListener` set on that `GridView`.

Override `areAllItemsEnabled` to return false, override `isEnabled` and do the check there.

Comment: I do the changes but still working wrong... I add to my code this:

                   Override
      public boolean isEnabled(int position){
       
       return true;
      }
      
      Override
      public boolean areAllItemsEnabled(){
       
       return false;
      }